# "God looked into the Torah to create the world"

Tags: creation, zohar

There is a known saying written in many places, including the Zohar and Medrash Bereishis Rabba, that says: "God looked at the Torah and then made the world". What is the meaning of this saying? The explanations I heard from rabbis are:

1. The laws of nature are hinted in the Torah. But, as far as I can see, the Torah doesn't make any claims about laws of nature... this is not at all the topic of the Torah.
2. The Torah is like a "user manual" for the world - keeping the Torah laws is essential for the existence of the world. But, a user manual for a product is usually created after the product - not before... a producer usually doesn't look at a user manual to create the product.

So, what is the meaning of this saying?

Comment: It's found in a range of sources, significantly predating (the publication of) the Zohar, including Tanna deVei Eliyahu and Bereishit Rabbah. I believe the import is that the Torah functions as a type of blueprint.

Comment: The expression comes from the Midrash Raba (Breishth 3:5 and 64:8) that says  כְּנֶגֶד סֵפֶר בְּרֵאשִׁית, שֶׁבּוֹ נִתְעַסֵּק הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא וּבָרָא אֶת עוֹלָמוֹ - and the phrase classicly used is הסתכל באורייתא וברא עלמא from the Zohar in  פ' תרומה דף קס''א ע''א

Comment: אִסְתָּכַּל בְּאוֹרַיְיתָא, וּבָרָא עָלְמָא.

Answer (score 6):

The way I was taught - by my high school Rebbe - it means that Hashem looked into the Torah and saw what was needed in order to fulfill the Torah and Mitzvot - and created a world that would enable one to do so.

E.g.: He saw he Mitzvah of honouring parents, so he created us with parents.

He saw that there is a need for Kosher and non-Kosher animals - and hence created them.

I found almost the identical idea in the Sefer [בני בנימין on אבות](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01516.html#HtmpReportNum0003_L2) who brings in the name of R' Chaim of Brisk:

> הגאון רבי חיים מבריסק זצ''ל היה מפרש את דברי מדרש רבא (תחילת פרשת בראשית) ''הקב''ה הסתכל באורייתא וברא עלמא'' כך: נדמה לנו שהתורה שצוותה אותנו לא תרצח או לא תגנוב, או איסור מאכלות אסורים, שקצים ורמשים וכדומה בגלל שהם מזיקים וגורמים השחתה לעולם כולו. ולכן אסרה אותם התורה. בא המדרש ואומר לנו שההיפך הוא הנכון. יתכן בהחלט שרציחה וגניבה יהיו קיום העולם. ומדוע הם באמת הרס לעולם? מפני שבתורה כתוב שאלו דברים רעים, כלומר מפני שהתורה אמרה אז זה נעשה רע או טוב. ‏
>
> בדומה לזה כל שאר המצוות שנצטווינו עליהם. כגון: אכילת מצה ומרור. לא נצטווינו בהם מפני שהייתה יציאת מצריים. להיפך מפני שהתורה ציוותה עליהם הרבה לפני - הייתה יציאת מצריים. מפני שהתורה ציוותה על כיבוד אב ואם נוצרו אב ואם ביולוגיים וצריכים אנו לכבדם. בגלל שיש מצוות מעקה בתורה - הקב''ה נותן לנו בית כדי שנקיים מצוותו, וכן על זה הדרך כל ציווי התורה הקדושה, ועל כך נאמר ''מי הקדימני ואשלם'' והבן זאת היטב! ‏

The Nefesh Hachaim (שער ד - פרק י and שער ד - פרק יא ) has  a more esoteric approach. But on a very basic level he seems to say:

Hashem used the Torah as a blue-print; reading the words and creating whatever he read.

> באור' כתיב בה בראשית ברא וכו' [את השמים] אסתכל בהאי מלה וברא את השמים. כתיב בה ויאמר אלהים יהי אור אסתכל בהאי מלה וברא את האור. וכן בכל מלה ומלה דכתיב בה באורייתא אסתכל קוב''ה ועביד ההוא מלה ‏

Comment: +1. It's worth noting that the first answer you give may be what the asker, above, transcribed as his option 1.

Comment: I have a question. If the above is true, it sounds like the Torah existed before Hashem. Why would G-d need to read the "manual" if he wrote it?

Comment: @JJLL - since Gcd is not corporeal, none of this can be taken in a literal sense. The Mishna in Chagiga already tells us that we are forbidden from trying to figure out what happened before the world came into existence.

Comment: @DannySchoemann  Yes, I know G-d is not corporeal. My question/comments was an analogy just as the OP's question was.

Comment: @JJLL - the second part of my comment is still valid - the order of things before the world was created is beyond the scope of what we may delve into.

Answer (score 1):

I heard once somewhere that compared the Torah to a filmstrip (the old-fashioned type) and the world to the projected image. The world is the actualization of the miniature print described in the Torah.
A similar comparison would be the Torah as DNA and the world as the cell - created from the instructions and an exact replication, though of different form and function.

Comment: OK, but where exactly in the Torah do you see a miniature-print of the entire world?